# "Вечно" + отрицание прилагательного

Tags: правописание

Как правильно писать: *вечнонезабытый* или *вечно незабытый*? *Вечно неженатый* или *вечнонеженатый*? Similar question for words with this structure.

I know that *вечнозелёный* (without *не*), for example, is written as one word, although I’m not sure if it’s an exception of sorts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As is often the case, there is no universal agreement on this matter. Rosenthal does acknowledge this in his style guide:

> Правописание сложных существительных и особенно прилагательных – одна из напряженных точек современной орфографии. Настоящий справочник в данном вопросе опирается на «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации 1956 г.», а также на нормативный «Орфографический словарь русского языка». Существует и несколько иной подход к написанию этих слов, например, в книге «Слитно или раздельно?» (опыт словаря-справочника) Б.3. Букчиной и Л.П. Калакуцкой (см. приложение в конце книги).

That said, in Rosenthal's style guide, there is no exception mentioned for adjectives with *не-*:

> Пишутся слитно сложные имена прилагательные, образованные из сочетаний слов, по своему значению подчиненных одно другому или по способу согласования *(железнодорожный, ср. железная дорога)*, или по способу управления *(вагоноремонтный, ср. ремонт вагонов)*, или по способу примыкания *(легкораненый, ср. легко ранить)*.
>
> Пишутся слитно многие сложные прилагательные, употребляемые в качестве научно-технических терминов или выражений в книжном языке, например: *азотнокислый, вечнозеленый, геологоразведочный, двояковогнутый, дикорастущий, длинноволокнистый, живородящий, заднебедренный, заразнобольной, засухоустойчивый, кишечнополостные, конноспортивный, контрольносеменной, кремнефтористоводородный, молочнокислый, молочнотоварный, мясоконсервный, насекомоядные, нервнотрофический, носоглоточный, обоюдоострый, обратноконический, обратносердцевидный, пахотнопригодный, первобытнообщинный, переднежаберный, плодоовощной, пологопадающий, поперечнополосатый, продолговатомозговой, прочнокомковатый, рассадопосадочный, реакционноспособный, резкопересеченный, свеженадоенный, свежескошенный, спинопоясничный, теснопальчатый, торфонавозный, торфоперегнойный, условнорефлекторный, формальнологический, хлебопекарный, хлебопроизводящий, хлопкоткацкий, хлопкоуборочный, хлопчатобумажный, хлористоводородный, хромолитографский, хромоникельмолибденовый, цветоустойчивый, церковнославянский, частновладельческий, частнохозяйственный, членистоногие, шерсточесальный, щелочноземельный, энергосиловой, энергохимический, языкотворческий, яйцезаготовительный.*
>
> Примечание 1. У многих сложных прилагательных данной группы первая часть образуется словами: *высоко-, низко-, глубоко-, мелко-, легко-, тяжело-, трудно-, широко-, узко-, много-, мало-, сильно-, слабо-, толсто-, тонко-, густо-, крупно-, круто-, остро-, плоско-, выше-, ниже-*

Some of the words formed with these adverbs plus *не-* are attested in the dictionaries: *высоконепредельный, слабонеоднородный, слабонепрерывный* etc.

Some authors do form single ad-hoc words using this pattern:

> - Из свеженезависимой Украины представители соседних армейских округов приезжали к Лебедю — предлагали поднять большую бучу. *[Эдуард Лимонов. Книга воды (2002)]*
> - Но сего весьма мало печатнаго находится ибо что Баронъ Герберштеинъ, Стриковскій и Гвагнинъ въ своихъ сочиненіяхъ, изъ столь изобильныхъ источниковъ почерпнули, оное состоитъ токмо въ сокращеніи многонедостаточномъ. *[Рассужденіе о двухъ бракахъ введенныхъ чужестранными писателями въ родъ великихъ Князей Всероссійскихъ // Ежемѣсячныя сочиненія къ пользѣ и увеселенію служащія. Генварь ― Іюнь, 1755 года, 1755]*
> - Или вы ждете не дождетесь перерыва между горячим и сладким, чтобы под чарующие звуки песен Шуфутинского и Антонова содрогаться в танцах с вечнонезамужними девочками из отдела продаж? *[М. Б. Бару. Навоз божьих коровок // «Волга», 2012]*

However, he also mentions:

> Различаются сложные прилагательные, образующие одно слово (со слитным или дефисным написанием, см. выше), и словосочетания, состоящие из наречия на -о (-е) и прилагательного или причастия (с раздельным написанием); к наречию, играющему роль отдельного члена предложения, можно поставить соответствующий вопрос. Ср.: *морально-этические проблемы – морально устойчивый человек (в каком отношении устойчивый?); общественно-исторические законы – общественно опасные элементы (опасные для кого?); промышленно-транспортный отдел – промышленно развитая страна (развитая в каком отношении?)*

I don't think it's useful as a formal test because these questions are ambiguous for half of the words above. E.g. *легкораненый* vs *легко раненный*: it's trivial to ask *раненный как?*, however *легкораненый* is nevertheless a thing. Yet this distinction is real, albeit hard to pinpoint.

If you use *вечнонеженатый* as some kind of intrinsic property in a group of people, something you would write with a dash in English: "you know the type — that still-looking-for-my-soulmate kind of guy", it's perfectly ok to write it as a single word in Russian.

If the adverb is a rhematic modifier to the adjective (meaning that it develops on the existing context rather than introducing a new one), then it can be written separately as two words: *Пришёл на школьную встречу и вечно неженатый, несмотря на кучу детей и штампов в паспорте, Павел, вокруг которого увивалась очередная пассия.*